# Can't input data into form field React

Tags: reactjs, string, forms, input

Hi I am making a form can someone please tell me why i cannot seem to enter text in the input fields. I did the type "text" and i thought that usually takes care of that. Any insight would be 100% appreciated.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class CreateExercise extends Component{

constructor(){
    super()

  this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
  this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);


    this.state = {
        username:'',
        description: '',
        duration: 0,
        users: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        users: ['test user'],
        username: 'test user'
    })
}

onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
        username: e.target.value
    });
}
onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
        description: e.target.value
    });
}
onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
        duration: e.target.value
    });
}




onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const exercise = ({
        username: this.state.username,
        description: this.state.description,
        duration: this.state.duration
    })

    console.log(exercise)

    window.location = '/';
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
           <h3>Create New Exercise Log</h3>
           <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
               <div className="form-group">
                   <label>Username: </label>
                   <select ref="userInput"
                   required
                   className="form-control"
                   value={this.state.username}
                   onChange={this.onChangeUsername}>
                     {
                         this.state.users.map(function(user) {
                             return <option
                             key={user}
                         value={user}>{user}
                         </option>
                         })
                     }  
                   </select>
               </div>
               <div className="form-group">
                   <label>Description: </label>
                   <input type="text"
                   required
                   className="form-control"
                   value={this.state.description}
                   onChange={this.onChangeDescription}
                   />
               </div>
               <div className="form-group">
                   <label>Duration (in minutes)</label>
                   <input 
                   type="text"
                   className="form-control"
                   value={this.state.duration}
                   onChange={this.onChangeDuration}
                   />
               </div>
               <div className="form-group">
                   <input type="submit" value="Create Exercise Log" className="btn btn-primary"/>
               </div>
           </form>
        </div>
    )


  }
}

export default CreateExercise;
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use {this.state} in your value fields. Theres no need for it.

also you have 3

```
onChangeUsername(e) {
```

im guessing you might want to update the other two methods

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some missing handlers and bindings. For example, if you add the event handler `onChangeDuration`:

```
onChangeDuration(e) {
    this.setState({
        duration: e.target.value
    });
}
```

and also do the binding inside the constructor method like:

```
this.onChangeDuration = this.onChangeDuration.bind(this);
```

Your duration field should be working.
You can apply the same logic to the description field as well.

Also do not forget to remove the unnecessary `onChangeUsername` methods. Hope that helps.